# Redux Form : setting value of hidden input in a loop

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

I am working with Redux Form and in that I am trying to set the value of Hidden Input field in a loop. But the value doesn't get submitted as the field was never touched. Is there a way to solve this or am I missing something?

```
const renderEmployeeFields = (fields) => {
  return fields.map((e, i) => {
    return (
        <Field
          key={e._id}
          name={`employeeSchedule[${i}].employee`}
          component={renderTextField}
          employeeId={e._id}
          label={e._id}
        />
    )
  })
}

const renderTextField = ({ input, label, employeeId}, autocompleteKey) => 
  <Input key={`${label}-input`} autoComplete={`${autocompleteKey}-${label}`} autoFocus {...input} value={employeeId} type='hidden'/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the value using the `initialValues` property (https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-initialvalues-object-lt-string-string-gt-code-optional-) so that they will be available on submit.

You don't need then the hidden input.